# Android C2DM How Many Messages Will Google Hold For an Offline Device?

Tags: android, queue, device, android-c2dm, offline

I've been looking for a specific explanation on how many messages Google queues for a particular offline device before it starts dropping them?  I've read that only 4 unique collapse keys can be queued for a device at a time but I just tested sending 5 messages with unique collapse keys and when i brought my device online, I got all 5.  I need to know how many messages I can expect Google to hold on to and also how many unique collapse keys I can have queued at once.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: For general knowledge, google announced GCM so try using that...

Comment: The thing is I'm already working on my own server side implementation. If I could just get the stats I'm looking for I'd be all set. I really don't want to change so much of the code I've written to use GCM. Thanks for the suggestion, but I really just need to know the answer to my Q.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that C2DM has been deprecated so I have no choice but to make the switch. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would likely be unhelpful since neither C2DM (now deprecated) or GCM will guarantee message delivery. But in any case the limit for GCM seems to be 100. You can queue upto a 100 messages for delivery without collapsing any of them. [Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  Would you happen to have a source for that number?

Comment: NVM found it on the Advanced Topics page of Google's GCM tutorial

Comment: I've already included the source in my answer. Glad you've got it all sorted out.